# MANOVA with variables from different datasets

Tags: r, na, manova, sample-size

*This question was already asked on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380795/manova-with-variables-from-different-datasets), but no one answered. Since I'm not sure which forum is the appropriate one, I post this here again with some data.*

I have done experiments on various characteristics of tree bark and now want to compare in how far the five examined tree species differ in regards to the assessed parameters. So, it was suggested that I should use a MANOVA to analyse my data and it seems reasonable to me. My analysis is conducted in `R`.

However, unlike most examples I've found on how to do a [MANOVA](http://userwww.sfsu.edu/efc/classes/biol710/manova/MANOVAnewest.pdf) (i.e. [here](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/manova), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48cZ2cMBpio), [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/manova-test-in-r-multivariate-analysis-of-variance)), my data stems from different measurements and from different individuals. Now, I've found only [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77812/manova-with-unequal-sample-sizes) thread discussing unequal sample sizes, but this targets only sample sizes within the explaining factor.

To illustrate a bit further, imagine I have *per tree species*...

- 9 measurements of the bark roughness.
- 4 measurements of the bark thickness,
- 3 pH measurements,
- 5 measurements of the water-holding capacity,
- 5 measurements of the water retention.

Of course, I could do separate ANOVAs for each of these variables (and I already did), but I think there should be some advantages in a MANOVA, right?

#### My Question:

Would a MANOVA be appropriate for such kind of data? Can I just ignore my different variable sizes? Is there an alternative way to do this or rather an alternative statistic test? Does my small sample size matter?

#### My results so far:

In `R`, I just put all the variables into one `data.frame` and filled the missing values due to unequal sample size by `NA`s (that's why there is the `nums` column in my `data.frame` below). Then, I ran a MANOVA like this: `pH + water content + thickness + roughness ~ tree species` with the `manova` function.

#### Example Data:

```
manova_df = structure(list(abbr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("AS", "BU", "CL", "MB", "PR"
), class = "factor"), nums = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), comb_rugosity = c(3.44, 2.29, 5.21, 1.45, 
2.84, 4.25, 1.54, 2.97, 1.38, 2.45, 9.44, 0, 0.58, 7.71, 5.53, 
0.84, 1.22, 1, 10.83, 15.77, 5.5, 8.49, 10.46, 9.16, 5.52, 6.55, 
1.77, 10.68, 13.43, 20.8, 8.82, 18.09, 15.1, 15.41, 16.3, 13.2, 
2.67, 0.95, 1.49, 2.7, 0, 0.92, 0.83, 0, 1.89), bark_mm = c(9.59, 
4.17, 17.23, 8.49, 3.58, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.06, 13.53, 6.33, 10.96, 
12.14, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17.94, 7.33, 10.54, 14.68, 16.66, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 8.52, 8.72, 7.57, 11.89, 6.41, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.59, 
9, 3.26, 5.81, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), pH = c(6.5, 7.33, 8.17, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.84, 3.71, 12.47, 4.39, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 11.04, 6.22, 5.41, 4.29, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.26, 11.18, 
6.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.42, 7.75, 4.33, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), whc = c(192, 251, 166, 170, 466, NA, NA, NA, NA, 308, 
187, 595, 324, 364, NA, NA, NA, NA, 171, 406, 790, 292, 579, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 672, 251, 700, 245, 260, 485, 383, NA, NA, 325, 
481, 338, 476, 968, NA, NA, NA, NA), ret = c(83, 90, 286, 309, 
374, NA, NA, NA, NA, 109, 159, 98, 164, 636, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
144, 234, 383, 178, 446, NA, NA, NA, NA, 275, 56, 178, 107, 125, 
367, 137, NA, NA, 132, 120, 142, 147, 330, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which looks like this (where `abbr` is the tree species, `nums` is the number of the measurement per tree species and the rest are the tree parameters):

```
> manova_df
# A tibble: 45 x 7
   abbr   nums comb_rugosity bark_mm    pH   whc   ret
   <fct> <int>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 AS        1          3.44    9.59  6.5    192    83
 2 AS        2          2.29    4.17  7.33   251    90
 3 AS        3          5.21   17.2   8.17   166   286
 4 AS        4          1.45    8.49 NA      170   309
 5 AS        5          2.84    3.58 NA      466   374
 6 AS        6          4.25   NA    NA       NA    NA
 7 AS        7          1.54   NA    NA       NA    NA
 8 AS        8          2.97   NA    NA       NA    NA
 9 AS        9          1.38   NA    NA       NA    NA
10 BU        1          2.45    8.06  7.84   308   109
# ... with 35 more rows
```

My analysis is pretty straightforward:

```
mano_mod = manova(cbind(pH, bark_mm, comb_rugosity, whc, ret) ~ abbr, data = manova_df)
> summary(mano_mod)
          Df Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
abbr       4 1.5708   1.4226     20     44 0.1628
Residuals 12
```

I did not include my real data here, but they follow the same structure. The given data are far from being significant, whereas my actual data are! My question is solely regarding the many `NA`s in my data and if the test is accurate.

(If anything is unclear, please ask.)

Comment: [stats.se] is the more appropriate site to post a problem like this one. If you elaborate your question over there as much as here, i'm willing to put a bounty on it to increase visibility.

Comment: @Jaap Nice, thank you! Have a look at [my question over at Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380795/manova-with-variables-from-different-datasets)

Comment: I think the problem is that the question is too long. Try to make it more concise, that way it will gain more traffic over at CV.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks for the advice. I edited it :)